# mysql query - to echo groups of products with foreach in stylable divs

Tags: mysql, css, foreach, echo

hope somone can help me - I have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category` = 100 AND `showme` = 1 `ORDER BY `nr` ASC";`
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
echo '<div class="'.$row->design.'">
  <img src="'.$row->img.'" width="100%"><br>
  <span><b>'.$row->name.'</b></span><br><span>'.$row->descr.'</span><br />
    <span>'.$row->preprice.'&nbsp;</span><span>'.$row->price.'</span><span>&nbsp;'.$row->unit.'</span></div>
';
}
```

It displays like this: http://gartenundhof.de/gartenundhof-produkte5.php

It should look about like:http://gartenundhof.de/gartenundhof-produkte.php (which has 3 separate queries)

Comment: You need to group them by category. 
```"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'category' = 100 AND 'showme' = 1  GROU_BY 'category' ORDER BY 'nr' ASC;```
I havent done RAW MySQL in a long while, but this should work :/ .
Also, instead of looping through your data in the first instance, you have too loop through the Categories. After that, for each category show the products.

Comment: Sorry I sent the wrong code:

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM 'products' ORDER BY 'category' ASC";
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `showme` = 1 `ORDER BY category,`nr` ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$category = -1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    if($category != $row->category) {
        $category = $row->category;
        eho "<h2>$category</h2>";
    }
    echo '<div class="'.$row->design.'">
    <img src="'.$row->img.'" width="100%"><br>
    <span><b>'.$row->name.'</b></span><br><span>'.$row->descr.'</span><br />
    <span>'.$row->preprice.'&nbsp;</span><span>'.$row->price.'</span><span>&nbsp;'.$row->unit.'</span></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 tables `Products` and `Categories`:

```
$categories_query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC";
$categories = mysql_query($categories_query);

while($category = mysql_fetch_object($categories)) {

  echo "Category: " . $category->name . "<br />";

  $products_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = " . $category->id . " AND showme = 1 ORDER BY nr ASC";

  while($product = mysql_fetch_object($products_query)) {
    echo "Product: " . $product->name . "<br />";
  }
}
```